# Change submit and reset button value text language according to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit, reset

i m sure its an easy question but i m very stack now... and i was wondering if anyone can help me..
my problem is the following...
I want to change from Greek to English language and vice verse the value of two buttons that is reset and submit, this is happening according to a variable that i take from a cookie.
**so far is working in two radio buttons using the label id sIndividual and sCompany and i want the same way to implement for the reset and the submit buttons** that i have in my form, were the html for the radios is,

```
    <p id="pRadio">
               <label>
                   <input type="radio" name="selectForm" value="Yes" checked="checked" /><img height="25" src="../images/individual.png" /><label id="sIndividual">Ιδιώτης</label></label>
               <label>
                   <input type="radio" name="selectForm" value="No" /><img height="25" src="../images/company.png"/><label id="sCompany">Επιχείρησης</label></label>
           </p>
```

and the javascript in one of my functions is like this,(i want to implement here for the submit and the reset button... )

```
    if (cookieVal === 'el_GR') {
    $('.breadcrumbs').html('Εγγραφή προμηθευτή');
    //$('#sReset').html('Επαναφορά'); //NOT WORKING WELL LOSING THE BUTTON IMAGE
   } else {
   $('.breadcrumbs').html('Supplier Registration');
   //$('#sReset').html('Reset');  //NOT WORKING WELL LOSING THE BUTTON IMAGE
   }
```

so the html for the two buttons submit and reset that i have is like that

```
       <p>
       <input type="reset" name="sReset" id="sReset" value="Επαναφορά">
       <input class="submit" id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Καταχώρηση" />        
       </p>
```

so i want to change the value of its button from Greek to English according to the if else above...for the radios is working... but for the reset and the submit no... :( 
I hope u understand the question..
any help would be really appreciated..
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

To change the text on a submit/button input you have to use .val() on a jquery object you already have like this:

```
$('#sReset').val('English or greek text');
```

And i have a fiddle showing you this with your markup here:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lrj1b5cp/

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing wrong here is `.html()` is a tag that we use for the dom elements that have an innerHTM that means tags like `<tag> innerHTML </tag>` these tags do not work with `.val()` but all the tags like `<tag/>` e.g `<input type="text" />` we have to change the `.val()` and not the `.html()` since they do not have a inner body

Comment: thank you as well Ekansh Rastogi but i was covered with the answer of the Snellface,,, thank you guys!!!